# How to find the expected number of tosses of dice to observe an outcome greater than or equal to what's on the first toss?

Tags: probability, expected-value

If I toss a six-sided dice and record its outcome. Then toss it repeatedly until I get an outcome which is greater than or equal to that on the first toss. What would be the expected number of tosses needed?

My attempt: If we don't include the first toss, then we can use the formula $E[X]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^niP(n=i)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $n$ be the toss when we get an outcome greater than or equal to that on the first toss. But I'm not sure if the formula is correct, and how to go on.

Comment: I am a little bit of confused.Is the answer $\dfrac{21}{36}$?

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince I don't know the answer... but how did you get that?

Answer (score 2):

If the first roll is a $1$ it takes one more roll to be equal or greater.  If it is a $2$ it takes $\frac 65$ of a roll on average because the chance of a lower roll is $\frac 16$.  If you toss a $3$ it takes $\frac 64$ and so on.  Counting the first roll the expected number of rolls is $$1+\frac 16\sum_{i=1}^6\frac 6i=\frac {69}{20}=3.45$$

Comment: can you elaborate on how you get $\frac{6}{5}$?

Comment: The probability for obtaining at least 2 on any roll is $5/6$. The count of rolls until success in a series of independent and identical trials is a Geometric Random Variable.  The expected count is this $6/5$.  Likewise for the rest.

Comment: Perhaps its worthwhile pointing out that $\sum_{i=1}^6\frac1i$, the expected number of rolls after the first one, is $H_6$, the sixth [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).